# What's the quickest way from a hook script to determine if a Subversion folder has been copied from somewhere else?

Tags: svn, directory, pre-commit-hook

I want to be able to determine, quickly, if a folder was created in its current location, or whether it has been moved/copied from somewhere else.

> svn log --verbose --stop-on-copy http://svn.example.com/path/to/folder

will give me the answer, by letting me inspect the last log entry for the "from ..." indication, but potentially yields a lot of log entries before giving me the one I'm interested in. Is there any shorter way?

My overall goal is to prevent certain commits in a pre-commit hook script unless the parent folder of a commit is an "original" folder - not copied from somewhere else, but created where it is. So something quick is essential.

Answer (score 0):

1. use file:// URLS which are quite faster
2. use a first `svn log <FILEURL> -q --stop-on-copy`
3. get the revision from last entry
4. use a `svn log <FILEURL> -v --limit 1` and examine the copyfrom path